# How to close div while open another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <div id="select1" data="select">
    <span>Select Option</span>
</div>
<div toggle="select1" style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
                option 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />
                option 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" />
                option 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="select2" data="select">
    <span>Select Option</span>
</div>
<div toggle="select2" style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
                option 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" />
                option 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="dog" />
                option 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data="select"]').click(function () {
            var selectdiv = $(this);
            $('[toggle="' + selectdiv.attr('id') + '"]').toggle(); ;
        })
    })
</script>
```

i have done it open the div above event .  how to set in that event to close the opened div .  also need to close div while click out of div or any action apart from div

if i opened one div need to close another one how to done it ?

actual output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you can hide all elements with the attribute `toggle` except the one that has to be opened.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data="select"]').click(function () {
        var selectdiv = $(this);
        var el = $('[toggle="' + selectdiv.attr('id') + '"]').toggle(); ;
        $('[toggle]').not(el).hide()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k77PF/)

Comment: also i have requested another query , if i click out of div all the div should be closed . How to done it ?

Comment: @ Arun if i do any other action , for eg : if i click button in my page all div should be closed . can u catch my point ? or else if i click any other area of my page all div should be close

Comment: @Smith any other element means elements other than `$('[data="select"]')` and `$('[toggle]')`?

Comment: @ Arun yes  normally i'm asking behavior of combobox